# Go JSON RPC v2 over HTTP

Tags: json, go, rpc

In the Go world is there any project implements the JSON RPC 2.0 (HTTP), especially the feature of batched query?

Some background that is, I know there's a Go built-in one but it's not over HTTP, and Gorilla looks to supports V2 (in the v2 folder, however I can't find documentation with it), but as I tested it response empty result for a combined request like "[{valid_request...},{valid_request...}]". Maybe it hasn't implemented the batched one. (Have I missed anything to get it right?)

Comment: Please see http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/rpc/json#overview . Last time I looked, Gorilla was JSON-RPC v1 only. I don't currently know of a v2 client for Go yet, but hopefully someone else will know of one.

Comment: Ya, but in the code base there's folder called "v2" under the "gorilla/rpc". I did some test and found this codec requires an extra field "jsonrpc":"2.0" in the request to get working, the "[...]" in params fields also gone.. however I didn't find any logic about batched query. One good part is the code is not complex, and it's possible to add batching by myself.

Comment: If you do manage to add batching, please send the Gorilla team a pull request in case they want to merge your changes.

Comment: Yes I managed to get batch working. In my way I need to modify those basic interfaces to treat batched query as default situation, and treat single query as special case of a normal batched query. The change is somewhat too big. I've no idea if the Gorilla teams really interested in. further, there're some production threshold control haven't been done, like limiting max query in one batch, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't find a ready Go server support for JsonRpc 2.0 for now, I modified the gorilla JsonRPC 2.0 to support the batched query. The forked repo is at https://github.com/jason-xxl/rpc . Just need to change the import path from "gorilla/rpc/v2" to "jason-xxl/rpc/v2_batch" to get a testable batched query enabled server. (Please let me know if I missed any one that already support 2.0 batch.)

Comment: Thanks Jason! Has your work been merged back to gorilla/rpc/v2? Or should I continue go get your fork?

Comment: Hi, I didn't pull request it back because it's more for our use cases (not fully test covered yet) and more importantly, in production you need to put threshold on max child request is allowed in a single parent request, other wise your server could be easily brought down by a valid huge request. however the code shows a possible implementation you can refer to.